# How to pass one argument from list and another argument in the built-in function map() in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, one could apply a function `foo()` to every element of a list by using the built-in function `map()` as follows:

```
def foo(x):
  return x*x

print map(foo, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This would print as one could guess: 1 4 9 16.

Lets say the function `foo()` now accepts two arguments instead of one, and is defined as follows:

```
def foo(x, y):
  return x+y
```

In this case, x is an element of the list, and y is some number which is the same for the whole list. How can we use map() in this case such that foo() is applied on every element of the list, while taking another argument y which is the same for every element?

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
print map(foo(:, 5), [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

which should give me: 6 7 8 9.

Is it possible in Python? There could be alternatives for this particular example of adding `'y'` to all the elements. But I am looking for an answer that would use `map()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a lambda function. This is treated just like a normal function, with the `x` value being the parameter for your iterator, and the return value being `x+5` in this case.

```
>>> def foo(x, y)
...   return x + y
...
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> map(lambda x: foo(x, 5), l)
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

For the record, @PaoloMoretti had this in before me :)

Comment: As I said, there could be alternatives. I am looking for an answer that would call the function foo() with the help of map().

Comment: @prashu Ah, I see what you're saying. I'll delete this if I can't think of anything else shortly.

Comment: @RocketDonkey: As I mentioned in my question, this is the preferred way to do what OP said. I would leave it up. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." And this one is it.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is with `functools.partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo(x, y):
...     return x + y
... 
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> map(partial(foo, y=2), l)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Another way is to change the way you define the function:

```
>>> def foo(y):
...     def inner(x):
...         return x + y
...     return inner
... 
>>> map(foo(2), l)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Incidentally, using `lambda` would be the most straightforward way to do this, as [Paolo Moretti said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950739/1142167). Any particular reason why you have to use `map()` the way you described?

Comment: wow! i really like these methods. i have never heard or seen them before. i am using python 2.6 are they available in that version?